# How to align elements 2 by 2 to the left in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, jtabbedpane

I am trying to make a JTabbedPane with the first tab with the following components aligned to the left but I can't get them to be left aligned 2 by 2 and at the moment it would be a JLabel + JTextField "line break" JLabel + JTextField...

Comment: please be more precise and show what you have tried

Comment: I'm trying to do this https://i.imgur.com/AdogBfI.png

Comment: there are layouts provided by swing, the one you are looking for might be the GridLayout (take a look at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/swing/swing_gridlayout.htm)

Comment: Thanks!! I have been able to do it

Answer (score 0):

Swing provides predefined layouts for common-use purposes. The one you might be looking for is `java.awt.GridLayout`. Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) for further information.